# androidのアプリでBookmarkを取得したい

Tags: android

以下の資料を参考にandroidアプリの勉強をしています。
http://tutorial.jp/prog/android/andman.pdf

p.112 「6.6.5 ブックマークを取得するアプリケーションの例」を参考にコードを書いてみたのですが以下のようなエラーがでました。どうすれば解決できますか？よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

javaのコードは以下です

```
package com.example.shimadzutsunehiko.getbookmmrk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getBookmark();
    }

    public void getBookmark(){
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                new String[]{
                        Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,
                        Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE
                },
                null,null,null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            int ititle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
            int iurl = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);
            ArrayAdapter adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            do {
                adapter.add("[" + c.getString(ititle) +"]" + c.getString(iurl));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        c.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

開発環境はandroidstudioです。

Answer (score 3):

APIレベル23からはフィールドが削除されているようです。

APIレベルを下げて開発するか、
代替えコードを書くしかなさそうですね。

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420427/some-issue-with-buildtoolsversion-23-0-1

上記が参考になりそうです。

Comment: レベルを下げればR.layoutのRでエラーがでました。
まだ始めたばかりなのでどのように解決できるかわかりませんが，R系のエラーは結構あるようなので，調べてみます。ありがとうございます。